# Returning PHP JSON to jQuery $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have no idea why I cannot get jquery to parse a JSON array from a PHP server side call.

Here is my jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"/Home/Profile/cb_profile.php",
  data:{loadProfile: JSON.stringify(itemsToPost)},
    success: function(data){
    var returnedItem = $.parseJSON(data);
  },
  error: function(e){
    console.log("We've had a error");
  },
});
```

Here is my PHP

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['loadProfile']))
{
  $connection = connectSQL();

  $userID = getID();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users where usersID = $userID";

  $results = query($connection,$query);

  $row = $results->fetch_assoc();

  $firstName = "Steve";

  echo json_encode(array("firstName" => $firstName));

  disconnectSQL($connection);
}
```

I get this error inside of firebug.

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

return window.JSON.parse( data );

Please help...

Comment: Possibly it's ran into an PHP error message, thus not providing the expected JSON string.

Comment: what is `data` in your success callback? jquery may have already parsed it for you if it recognized the string as JSON

Comment: alert the data and check what php returning???

Comment: I don't see where your PHP script is using the POSTed JSON in `loadProfile`.  Are you sure it is returning data as expected?

Comment: You do not need this part at all:


    var returnedItem = $.parseJSON(data);

You can say instead of that: `var returnedItem = eval(data);`

Comment: But first do console.log(data) to see what are you geting in response.

Comment: If I remove my dataType and console.log I get this -> {"firstName":"Steve"} and if I run eval() I get this -> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"firstName":"Steve"} @pregmatch

Comment: what do you get when access this url /Home/Profile/cb_profile.php ?

Comment: there's obviously nothing wrong with your json syntax because `JSON.parse('{"firstName":"Steve"}')` works. My guess is your script is returning more than that, such as an extra character before or after the json string.

Comment: As @Kevin B said thre must be something else in your php file.

Comment: @pregmatch I get a blank page when I try to load /Home/Profile/cb_profile.php

Comment: remove if(isset($_REQUEST['loadProfile']))
{ from php. do not forget to remove } at the end of file also. comment all sql just leave $firstName = "Steve";

  echo json_encode(array("firstName" => $firstName)); and then try you r ajax call again.

Comment: this sounds like a fishy character stored in your database that can't be encoded properly

Comment: BANG that worked, I commented out everything and now it works. Now I have to track down what's causing the problem. @pregmatch

Comment: If I have to guess problem is either here $userID = getID(); //what is this some function? and put disconnectSQL($connection); before echo json_encode.

Comment: getID grabs if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))
   echo "0";
  else
   echo "1"; Which is probably causing the problem. @pregmatch

Comment: there you go. you can not echo. if you do that page response will not be valid json code.

Comment: @44 6f 6f 20 44 6f 6f I have added answer. Tell me if this is working for you. Please accept answer if yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44644/discussion-between-pregmatch-and-44-6f-6f-20-44-6f-6f)

Answer (score 0):

Just change DataType key for the  ajax call to json and you won't need to do the parseJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a typo in query? UsersID to UserID. You probably have error in php script. Check firebug or chrome dev tool. See the response you get from server what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 echo json_encode(array("firstName" => urlencode($firstName)));
```

Comment: What is you default charset?

Comment: Please try this $firstName = utf8_encode("Steve"); if not works try $firstName = utf8_decode("Steve");

Comment: Both resolve to the error section in the jQuery. @Pedro Monteiro

Answer (score 0):

I found the real problem. For some reason a BOM or Byte Order Mark sneaked into my response and caused $.parseJSON() to die. I resolved this problem by adding .trim() to my response `var returnedItem = $.parseJSON(data.trim());`.